# Can we know which client side script is performing a particular action on a website?

Tags: web-application, javascript, client-side, devops

Recently in an website I had noticed that the data which is received from the server is not the data that is being displayed.I think it would have been modified on client-side. So, Is there any way by which I can know which action is being performed by which script?

Comment: By data i mean value of a particular variable.

Comment: Generally: no.  You would have to work your way through the javascript to find it.  However, I'm not quite sure how this is a security question?

Comment: [Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript) tools in browsers might help but that's probably a question for stack overflow

Comment: You may be able to track down the script using the `developer tools` function in your web browser.  Use the `networking` tab to find requests from the client-side scripts to the server, and examine the responses for the data that you are interested in.  You can also use the `inspector` to find the DOM element that the data is displayed in, then you may be able to find the script by searching for scripts that contain a reference to this DOM element.  You should be able to find the script by using techniques similar to those above, and perhaps a little monkey-patching.